# Java CUP produces Shift-Reduce conflict when parsing a grammar for a C++ type language

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, lr-grammar, cup

Me and my team are trying to recreate a C++ type language and we are stuck on a shift-reduce conflict that arises from the non-terminal responsible for function definitions. The grammar goes like:

...

`program ::= program variable_declaration SEMICOLON| programa function_declaration SEMICOLON| program function_definition | program type_definition SEMICOLON;`

`function_definition ::= type IDENTIFIER OPENBRACKET argument_list CLOSEBRACKET block;`

`block ::= OPENCURLYBRACKET instruction_sequence CLOSECURLYBRACKET;`

`instruction_sequence ::= instruction_sequence instruction | /*EPS*/;`

`instruction ::= non_balanced_instruction | balanced_instruction;`

`balanced_instruction::= IF OPENBRACKET expression CLOSEBRACKET balanced_instruction ELSE balanced_instruction| not_if_instruction;`

`non_balanced_instruction ::= IF OPENBRACKET expression CLOSEBRACKET instruccion | IF OPENBRACKET expresion CLOSEBRACKET balanced_instruction ELSE non_balanced_instruction ;`

`not_if_instruction ::= block| while| for| switch| semicolon_instruction;` 
...

Upper cases mean terminal symbols, while lower cases mean non terminal ones. function_declaration represents prototypes, whereas function_definition refers to the implementation of the function.

The output from CUP is:

Shift/Reduce conflict found in state #197
between instruction ::= balanced_instruction(*)
and     non_balanced_instruction ::= IF OPENBRACKET expression CLOSEBRACKET balanced_instruction (*) ELSE non_balanced_instruction
and     balanced_instruction ::= IF OPENBRACKET expression CLOSEBRACKET balanced_instruction (*) ELSE balanced_instruction
under symbol ELSE

We have been debbugging for days, we are desperate. We found out that the conflict dissapears when we remove the whole non-terminal **function_definition**.

We tried rebuilding the grammar in small increments until finding the exact non-terminal that caused the conflict.

Any help is truly appreciated :)).

Comment: This is normal. All languages with `if/else` and blocks have this S/R conflict. It should resolve in favour of a shift to get the expected parse behaviour.

Comment: Your grammar has a couple (probable) typos: the production for `program` refers to `programa` and the production for `non_balanced_instruction` refers to `instruccion` and `expresion`. Also, the production for `program` has no non-recursive right-hand-side (i.e., no way to terminate). These might be unrelated to the error message you're asking about, but you should fix them first.